# Displaying the result of a sql query inside a user defined function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have to print the ages of Players but using a user defined function. The below code is executing successfully because I am just returning something. But how can I print the result below?
Here are the results when I execute it!
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYeZc.png)

```
CREATE FUNCTION calculateage()
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
    return (Select datediff(YY, BIRTH_DATE, GETDATE()) FROM PLAYERS)
END
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Must the function return the wqhole result set? I'd consider it more typical to have a function that gets a date and calculates the age from this date and use this function in a query. As is, you seem to be selecting all players' ages, but the function is supposed to return a single int

Comment: its my sql! even if a use a specific date e.g '1948-09-01' instead of Birth_Date, the query get successfully executed but still not printing the ages below

Comment: This function as a wrong syntax... Do you want to return a single age of one player (which conduct to write a scalar function) or all the age of all the payers (which conduct to write a viexw or a table function). And as a matter of fact your calcuylur is wrong for the age....

Comment: @SQLpro  A single age of one player! I think there has to be a print call to print the query result.But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Codeit: What is "its my sql!" supposed to mean? Do you mean the DBMS MySQL? Or was a_horse_with_no_name right by tagging this with the DBMS SQL Server? What tool do you use to execute SQL statements? What command do you use to call the function?

Answer (score 1):

A correct age calculus is done by the above scalar function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION calculateage(@birth_date AS DATE)
RETURNS SMALLINT
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN DATEDIFF(year, @birth_date, GETDATE()) - 
           CASE 
              WHEN MONTH(@birth_date) > MONTH(GETDATE()) 
                   OR MONTH(@birth_date) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(@birth_date) > DAY(GETDATE()) 
                 THEN 1
              ELSE 0
           END;
END
GO
```

As a test, you can execute this query :

```
SELECT dbo.calculateage('2000-01-01'), dbo.calculateage('2000-02-01')
```

Comment: Executing successfully but not printing the ages!

Comment: @Codeit: Are you saying that you run the sample query SQLpro has suggested for testing and that query does not result in an error, but is not returning a row either? This seems highly unlikely.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes! see this https://ibb.co/jJxRwYT

Comment: You've created a function and it compiled well. Now this function exists in your database and waits to be executed. One way to execute it is the suggested test query `SELECT calculateage('2000-01-01'), calculateage('2000-02-01')`. Another that should work for your table is `select p.*, calculateage(p.birth_date) as age from players p`.

Comment: @Codeit: Is this your first time with SQL? The *test* query is to *test* the function. It gets two dates and returns two ages of course. Don't you see this? Just look at the query. Your player table is not even involved. Use the other query I have suggested to select from your players table instead.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Sorry! Yes this is my first time with sql! Which query did you suggest to select from the players table instead?

Comment: `select p.*, calculateage(p.birth_date) as age from players p`

Comment: Now i called my initial function and this is the error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: You replaced SQLpro's correct function with your incorrect one? Writing a function is a one-time thing. You create it and from that moment on it is in your database and stays there forever. Then you use it in queries whenever you want.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Now I am getting my concepts cleared! What changes will I have to do in the age calculus code you provided to make it a procedure , not a function!

Comment: Ah, you want to make a procedure that you execute instead of running a query and that procedure shall return players wit their age, just as a query would do. I don't know how this is done in your DBMS. I don't know your DBMS even. Is it MySQL or SQL Server now? If you want to write such a procedure and your DBMS supports this. I would probably still keep Codeit's function and use this inside the procedure.

Comment: Its MySql! And I am using Sql server management studio!

Comment: I read the syntax of procedure and here is what I did! https://ibb.co/86cp5CK

Comment: But when I call it using Exec calculatetopfiveages . It says Procedure or function 'calculatetopfiveages' expects parameter '@BIRTH', which was not supplied.

Comment: Maybe you should first learn plain SQL, before starting to write procedures. You seem to expect that the DBMS magically knows what you have in mind. Look at your new procedure. It has two parameters BIRTH and BIRTH_DATE. So how can you be surprised that the DBMS complains that these are not supplied when you don't supply them when calling the procedure? Then look at the code inside the procedure. It returns a number (years) that it is calculating from the values BIRTH and BIRTH_DATE. But a procedure is not supposed to return a value. A *function* returns a value...

Comment: Then you call this calculatetopfiveages. Top 5? Related to what? How can a procedure that gets two values return top 5 ages? And don't you want to involve your players table somehow? As mentioned: Learn one thing at a time. Keep away from procedures and functions for the moment. Learn SQL. Learn how to select data you want from tables. When you are comfortable with this, start moving functionality to procedures and functions, in case you still want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this: `select dbo.calculateage()`

Comment: while using dbo.calculateage() ,  the query get successfully executed but still not printing the ages  below.

Comment: maybe it's because there's no data in your table?

Comment: @Codeit ok,if you only want to print a single age of one player, i think you should add a WHERE condition like Name="blabla" or something like that